# Determinant equal to 0 matlab

Tags: matlab, determinants

I'm learning how to use Matlab. I've a question about the matrix A:
A=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]
Obviously the determinant should be equal to 0. But actually I got the value: 6.661338147750939e-016
What is wrong?

I know it's pretty much zero. What I want is to have zero as result. Is there a way to get 0 (precise result) or 6.661338147750939e-016 is all I can get?

Comment: Nothing's wrong. Just numerical inaccuracies. The error is of the order of [eps](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), so it's normal

Answer (score 3):

Matlab computes the determinant using LU decomposition, so the determinant is computed as a floating point number even for a matrix of integers.  What you're seeing is the typical numerical error in floating point calculations.

If you're trying to check if the matrix is singular,  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13146750/254364) gives a bunch of alternatives that are better than using the determinant.