# Is there a way to tell what makes a particular numpy array singular?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to generate a few very large arrays, and at least one is ending up being singular, which is made obvious by this familiar error message:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 90, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Of course I do not want my array to be singular, but I am more interested in determining WHY my array is singular.  What I mean by this is that I would like to have a way to answer the following questions without manually checking each entry:

1. Is the array square? (I believe this is returned by a separate error message, which is convenient, but I'll include this as a singularity property anyway)
2. Are any rows populated only by zeros?
3. Are any columns populated only by zeros?
4. Are any rows not linearly independent of all other rows?

For relatively small arrays, the first two conditions are easily answered by visual inspection.  However, because my arrays are substantially large, I do not want to have to go in and manually check each array element to see if any of those conditions are met.

I tried pulling up the `linalg.py` script to see if I could see how it determines a matrix to be singular, but I could not tell how it determines a matrix to be singular.

**(this paragraph was edited for clarity)**
I also tried searching for info online, and nothing seemed to be of help.  Most topics seemed to only answer some form of the following questions/objectives:  1) "I want Python to tell me if my matrix is singular" or 2) why is Python giving me this error message".  Because I already know that my matrix/matrices are singular, neither of these two questions are of importance to me.

Again, I am not looking for an answer along the lines of, "Oh, well this particular matrix is singular because . . .". I am looking for a method I can use immediately on ANY singular matrix to determine (especially for large arrays) what is causing the singularity.

Is there a built-in Python function that does this, or is there some other relatively simple way to do this before I try to create a function that will do this for me?

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm sorry, it's supposed to be one question.  How is it coming across as multiple questions, so I can edit it to make it clearer?

Comment: The "Q1" and "Q2" look like multiple questions.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I'll make it clear that I am not trying to answer those (because I already have the answer to those questions if I know my matrix is singular).

Comment: "Are any rows not linearly independent of all other rows?" - well, of course. If all rows were linearly independent, your matrix wouldn't be singular. You can't really pin the blame for a matrix's singularity on any one part of it. Depending on what your matrices look like, though, you might be interested in its nullspace or the smallest linearly dependent set of its rows.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I am trying to figure out WHICH set of rows are linearly dependent. I do understand that, by definition, there are some linearly dependent rows.

Answer (score 1):

Singular matrices have at least one eigenvalue equal to zero. You can create a diagonalizable singular matrix by starting from its eigenvalue decomposition:

```
A = V D V^{-1}
```

D is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. So create any matrix V, the diagonal matrix D that has at least one zero in the diagonal, and then A will be singular.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this would help me identify what quality of a particular matrix is causing it to be singular.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way of checking is by computing an SVD. This is what the function `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank` uses to compute the rank, and you can then check if `matrix_rank(M) == M.shape[0]` (assuming a square matrix).

For more information, check out this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13146750/10601) to a similar question for Matlab users.

The rank of the matrix will tell you how many rows aren't zero or linear combinations, but not specifically which ones. It's a relatively fast operation, so it might be useful as a first-pass check.

Comment: Hmm... that helps some, but I would still like to know which columns/rows are causing the problems.  I think I'll look at the code for matrix_rank to see if I can make a version of it that will spit out which rows it determines are causing the matrix to be singular.