# Find roots of characteristic equation of a matrix function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that is a function of some parameter A=A(x). I would like to find the points x where this matrix becomes singular. Example (I have a large matrix though):

```
syms x
A=[x sin(x); cos(x^2) 2.5];
```

So far I have been symbolically computing the determinant of the matrix and then used fzero or newtzero to find the roots of that characteristic equation. I.e.

```
detA = det(A);
fzero(matlabFunction(detA),startingGuess)
```

Then I found this: [How to find out if a matrix is singular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145948/how-to-find-out-if-a-matrix-is-singular), where it is advocated to not use the determinant under any circumstances.

Indeed the symbolic determinant calculation is terribly slow. However I tried to use rank(A) instead as suggested in the link and it does not seem to work for symbolic matrices.

**Is there any way to implement the suggestions in the link for finding the roots of a characteristic equation of a matrix that is given symbolically?**

Comment: Avoiding the determinant is good advice for numeric computations. Not sure if that applies to symbolic

Comment: Symbolic maths in a numerical machine (a computer) are slow. The advantage of symbolic maths is that you can indeed use `det(A)` safely, as maths are computed following "laws", but anything symbolic will always be slower than anything numeric. So you need to choose, slow but accurate maths, or fast but numerical-based "inaccurate" maths (not really inaccurate, just not perfect ).

Comment: @AnderBiguri Since I use fzero in the end the roots are found numerically anyway, so I don't mind that. The only reason I do the symbolic determinant is because the matrix is is given symbolically and I don't know what else to do. If there is a direct numerical way that would be great too.

Comment: @Mrphlng I am confused. You want to numerically find which values make the determinant zero, but you already know them because you solve with `fzero`? Then.... you already know them?

Comment: @AnderBiguri sorry if I was unclear. I want to find *which values make the matrix singular*. I used the determinant as a criterion, which as pointed out in the other link is not a very good criterion. So I am asking for other criteria that also work for symbolic matrices. Rank seems to fail pretty badly, it only gives me 2 which is clearly not true for all values of x.

Comment: @Mrphlng and what do you solve with `fzero`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I make the symbolic determinant a matlab function and then find the roots of that with fzero

Comment: The symbolic determinant is probably quite fast to compute, if you do not try to find its roots. right? it takes 4 miliseconds in my PC. There are no complicated maths behind it, it just takes indexes and mutiplies them in specific order.

Comment: @AnderBiguri see edit for clarification. Yes, that is quite fast. however the roots fzero gives me then are terribly inaccurate (probably for reasons pointed out in the linked question resulting from the use of determinant as the criterion for singularity). What do I mean by inaccurate? It sometimes finds no roots at all, sometimes finds random roots that don't actually make the matrix singular. I was hoping that could be resolved by using a differnt criterion.

Comment: @Mrphlng No, the linked question has nothing to do with your case. The symbolic determinant is 100% accurate, as it is symbolic. I have run the `fzero` in my PC. All roots found, with any random initial guess are always smaller than `1e-15`, i.e. zero. From your matrix, it is ovbious that zero is a possible value

Comment: @AnderBiguri the problem is that as a function it is pretty badly behaved and not suited for finding the roots numerically (which is I think what the linked question implies?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138920/discussion-between-ander-biguri-and-mrphlng).

Comment: 1) What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? 2) Is your matrix a function of one parameter only? Both questions can be important.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis 1) That is far too long to describe unfortunately. However my actual *question* is if there is a better way to find the values of the parameter where the matrix is singular than to set det=0. The determinant does not seem to be the actual issue in my case, however the question stands. 2) Yes.

Comment: About (1) - is the matrix by any change a Jacobian matrix?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Unfortunately not. I will look up the techniques mentioned in your answer though, maybe they will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach would be the following: a square matrix `A` is singular if and only if the homogeneous linear (with respect to the vector `y`) system `A*y = 0` has nontrivial solutions `y <> 0` (which is equivalent to `det(A) = 0` and `rank(A) = 0` among others. So a more or less standard, as I recall from the past, technique to compute such points x is to solve the nonlinear system

```
A(x)*y = 0   (1)
||y||  = 1   (2)
```

This way you can compute a point `x*` and a vector `y*` such that `A(x*)` is singular and `y*` is an eigenvector corresponding to the zero eigenvalue of `A(x*)`.

If I remember correctly, you can also solve the somewhat easier system

```
A(x)*y = 0   (1)
<y,c>  = 1   (2a)
```

where `c` is "almost" any nonzero random vector (normalize it to 1 to avoid numerical problems).

As a matter of fact there is an enormous bibliography on the subject - you can look for saddle-node bifurcation computations (in case `A(x)` is the Jacobian of a vector field), or for "distance to instability".

Comment: +1 this is great, dunno why I didn't come up with this myself. Actually I started with this problem but didn't think I could implement it directly, so I went to the determinant version. If you could provide any suggestions and possibly some code on how to implement this with a symbolic matrix in MATLAB you would earn a green tick too :)

Comment: Ha ha, it's been almost a decade since I last wrote code in Matlab... I think that you must be in better shape than me. But why you want to compute a symbolic solution? I would be rather surprised if this was possible to tell you the truth.

Comment: haha fair enough. I don't really want a symbolic *solution* I just have a symbolic matrix at hand to start with.

Comment: Then you can implement a nonlinear solver of the system `Ay=0, <y,y>=1`, e.g. a Newton-Raphson  solver, with an initial point `x0`. There is also another approach, described in a conference paper of mine (my only paper, actually :-), where the idea was to to compute a **QR** factorization of the matrix **A** `(x0)` and then try to render the last diagonal element of **R**, say `r_n`, to zero. To this end you can compute the derivative **dR/dx** from a linear system of equations (or approximate it with finite differences), and effectively solve numericcally the equation `r_n(x) = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

From a [discussion with Ander Biguri](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138920/discussion-between-ander-biguri-and-mrphlng) it seems that the determinant is actually a perfectly fine method of approaching this problem. The problem seems to be to solve the final equation in a stable manner, which would be a different question.