# How to check a matrix is not singular with a computer

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I would like to know a robust way to check if a matrix is not singular using a computer. I know using the determinant (requiring it to be non zero) can be misleading as it cannot distinguish between a case where a matrix is indeed singular and due to numerical errors you get a very small value (e.g.~10^-12) and a case like 10^-12*I which again gives a very small determinant whereas the matrix is definitely not singular (it is orthogonal).

There is a good link ([How to find out if a matrix is singular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145948/how-to-find-out-if-a-matrix-is-singular/13146750#13146750)) arguing one can use the condition of the matrix, or in other words the ratio of biggest singular value over smallest singular value.

However isn't this problematic again? The 2x2 matrix [10^8  0; 0  10^-8] is orthogonal and therefore definitely not singular, however its singular values are 10^8 and 10^-8 (condition number 10^16), therefore according to the link above it would be classified as singular.

Is a correct way to normalise the rows before singular value decomposition and then simply check the smallest singular value to be small (e.g. smaller than 10^-7)?

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: Keep in mind that *any* computation using floating point numbers will result in rounding errors, so it is impossible to say whether a matrix is actually singular or not. That is why we actually use things like the condition number to express how close a matrix is to being singular. Why don't you test the different methods to see which one produces the most accurate results? PS: It is not too difficult to come up with cases where normalizing the rows actually deteriorates the problem.

Comment: The link is right: you must find the matrix’s singular values, and compare the ratio of min/max singular value to machine precision (or some multiple thereof, e.g., `eps(1)*1e3`). The example you cite (`diag([1e8 1e-8])`) *is singular to machine precision* since its condition number is on the order of `eps(1)`. Any numerical operation you perform on this matrix is bound to run into large errors as described by @LuisMendo’s answer. There is *no* way to “pre-normalize” a matrix before SVD that’ll change the condition number.

Comment: (If you really need to deal with examples like `diag([1e8 1e-8])`, I have used the pure-Python `mpmath` package, with arbitrary-precision matrixes, very successfully in the past. But goodbye to speed, since your CPU accelerates double-precision floating-point math to >2 GHz but arbitrary-precision must be done in software.)

Answer (score 2):

The condition number of a matrix measures how sensitive the linear system **A** **x** = **b** is with respect to perturbations in **b**. A large condition number means that a **relative perturbation** in `b` can be greatly amplified in the solution `x`.

The term *relative perturbation* here means how much the original and perturbed vectors differ, compared to the size of the original vector. Specifically, let `b1` denote the perturbed version of `b` and `x1` the corresponding perturbed solution. The relative perturbation in `b` (or in `x`) is defined as `norm(b-b1)/norm(b)` (or `norm(x-x1)/norm(x)`).

With this definition, the **significance of the condition number** can be phrased as follows: a large condition number means that `norm(x1-x)/norm(x)` *can* be much larger than `norm(b1-b)/norm(x)`. (For a proof of this result see *Applied Linear Algebra*  (3rd ed.) by B. Noble and J.W. Daniels, page 271; or [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695627/relation-between-condition-number-and-perturbed-matrix) at Mathematics Stack Exchange.)

Your **example matrix** is

```
A = [10^8 0; 0 10^-8];
```

with

```
>> cond(A)
ans =
     1.0000e+16
```

Consider the following system using this matrix:

```
b = [1; 0]; % original b
x = A\b; % original solution
b1 = b + 0.01; % perturbed b
x1 = A\b1; % perturbed solution
```

This gives the solutions `x = [1e-8; 0]` (original) and `x1 = [1.01e-08; 1e6]` (perturbed). The relative perturbation in the solution is

```
>> norm(x-x1)/norm(x)
ans =
     1.0000e+14
```

As you can see, it is much larger than the relative perturbation that was introduced in `b`,

```
>> norm(b-b1)/norm(b)
ans =
   0.0141
```

Note that for other choices of `b` the relative perturbation may not get so dramatically amplified. The condition number characterizes the worst-case behaviour over all possible choices of `b`.

On the other hand, consider the **row-normalized version** of `A`:

```
B = A;
B(1,:) = B(1,:)/norm(B(1,:));
B(2,:) = B(2,:)/norm(B(2,:));
```

This is just the identity matrix:

```
>> B
B =
     1     0
     0     1
```

which, of course, is as well-conditioned as it gets. So now the relative perturbation in `x` is not amplified with respect to that in `b`:

```
y = B\b;
y1 = B\b1;
```

gives

```
>> norm(y-y1)/norm(y)
ans =
   0.0141
```

which is *the same* as the relative perturbation in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition number does not decide whether the matrix is singular or not, it shows whether the solutions obtained are robust w.r.t. RHS of the linear system or not. A nonsingular matrix might have very bad condition.

A matrix `A` is singular if any of its columns can be expressed as a linear combination of the remaining columns. This is equivalent to saying that `A` is nonsingular if and only if it is full rank. So a rank-revealing factorization should be used. The recommended way (at least this is what I was taught back then!) to do this is the [Rank-revealing QR factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRQR_factorization).