# Is there an equivalent to matlab's rcond() function in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm porting some matlab code that uses rcond() to test for singularity, as also [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001800/how-to-find-if-a-matrix-is-singular-in-matab) (for matlab singularity testing).

I see that there is a cond() function in Julia (as also in Matlab), but rcond() doesn't appear to be available by default:

```
ERROR: rcond not defined
```

I'd assume that rcond(), like the Matlab version is [more efficient than 1/cond()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rcond.html).  Is there such a function in Julia, perhaps using an add-on module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Julia calculates the condition number using the ratio of maximum to the minimum of the eigenvalues](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/b33f5782d2b8d8c8bf569fb152af46dbf2e3ec29/base/linalg/dense.jl#L432-L442) (got to love open source, no more MATLAB black boxs!)

Julia doesn't have a `rcond` function in Base, and I'm unaware of one in any package. If it did, it'd just be the ratio of the maximum to the minimum instead. I'm not sure why its efficient in MATLAB, but its quite possible that whatever the reason is it doesn't carry though to Julia.

Comment: Including a link to the implementation in your answer is very cool.  Thanks!

Could matlab's rcond be avoiding calculation of all the singular values, perhaps getting an estimate of just the biggest and smallest?

Comment: Matlab probably just uses LAPACK's [dgecon.f](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgecon.f), which could be similarly exposed (and further specialized for different matrix types) in Julia.

Comment: Ah, it's [already wrapped](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/b33f5782d2b8d8c8bf569fb152af46dbf2e3ec29/base/linalg/lapack.jl#L3219-L3285) and used in [some cases](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/b33f5782d2b8d8c8bf569fb152af46dbf2e3ec29/base/linalg/lu.jl#L153).  It'd probably be good to do some benchmarking to see if an explicit Matlab-style `rcond` is warranted.

Answer (score 3):

Matlab's `rcond` is an optimization based upon the fact that its an *estimate* of the condition number for *square* matrices.  In my testing and given that its help mentions LAPACK's 1-norm estimator, it appears as though it uses LAPACK's [dgecon.f](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgecon.f).  In fact, this is exactly what Julia does when you ask for the condition number of a square matrix with the 1- or Inf-norm.

So you can simply define

```
rcond(A::StridedMatrix) = 1/cond(A,1)
```

You can save Julia from twice-inverting LAPACK's results by manually combining [`cond(::StridedMatrix)`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/b33f5782d2b8d8c8bf569fb152af46dbf2e3ec29/base/linalg/dense.jl#L439) and [`cond(::LU)`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/b33f5782d2b8d8c8bf569fb152af46dbf2e3ec29/base/linalg/lu.jl#L153), <strike>but the savings here will almost certainly be immeasurable.</strike>  Where there is a measurable savings, however, is that you can directly take the `norm(A)` instead of reconstructing a matrix similar to A through its LU factorization.

```
rcond(A::StridedMatrix) = LAPACK.gecon!('1', lufact(A).factors, norm(A, 1))
```

In my tests, this behaves identically to Matlab's `rcond` (2014b), and provides a decent speedup.