# What is the correct way in julia to check if the inverse of a matrix exists?

Tags: math, matrix, julia

I'm learning Julia, and I know that there are built in methods, such as, `det()`, and `inv()` that come in handy in matrix. I wrote a code:

```
function soln()
  # coeff matrix of the given SoLE
  A::Matrix{Int64} = Matrix{Int64}([
    1   2  -3;
    -3  1  -2;
    5   3  -4
  ]);

  detA = det(A);  # 6.2172489379008774e-15 approximately zero

  println("detA = $detA");

  if(detA == 0)
    println("Soln does not exist!");
    return;
  else
    println("Solution exists!");
  end

  A⁻¹ = inv(A);  # this does not crash!
  display(A⁻¹);
end
```

If you calculate the determinant by hand, you'll see that det(A) is 0. So I was expecting the function will return from the `if block`. but no, because the builtin method calculates
the determinant = 6.2172489379008774e-15, which is approximately zero, but not equal to zero.

I want my code to return from the `if block`. So I wrote a function to calculate the determinant, and check the existence of the inverse matrix:

```
function checkIfInvMatrixExists(A::Matrix{Int64})::Bool
  pair = size(A);
  row = pair[1];
  col = pair[2];
  
  println("r = $row, c = $col");
  N = row # = col
  det = 0

  v = Array{Int64}(undef, 2, N);
  
  # println(v);

  for i in 1:N
    v[1,i] = i
    v[2, i] = i
  end

  println(v);

  for j in 1:N
    temp = 1
    for i in 1:N
      r = (v[1,i] + j - 1)
      if r > N
        r -= N
      end
      c = v[2,i]
      
      temp *= A[r,c]
    end
    det += temp    
  end


  println(det)

  for i in 1:N
    v[1,i] = N - i + 1
    v[2, i] = i
  end

  # print(v);
  for j in 1:N
    temp = 1
    for i in 1:N
      r = (v[1,i] + j - 1)
      if r > N
        r -= N
      end
      c = v[2,i]
      
      temp *= A[r,c]
    end
    det -= temp
  end

  println(det)
  if det == 0
    return false
  else
    return true
  end

end
```

Since it calculates the determinant = 0, and so returns from the `if block`.

I was expecting a builtin, and efficient function to do this for me. So what is the julia way of checking existence of the inverse matrix?

Comment: Hi! You've stumbled upon an interesting question. Long-story short: Julia uses LU factorisation of matrices to compute the determinant, and while doing that, converts the matrix to floating-point (hence the approximation). Here for a longer discussion of the issue and suggested solutions: [JuliaLang / issue #40128 /  Integer-matrix determinants are not computed exactly](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/40128)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Julia, but it looks like if you declare your matrix as Rational{BigInt} instead, function `det` should work without approximations.

Comment: Or do you have access to a function called `det_bareiss`?

Comment: The least you could (and should) do is to check `if (detA ≈ 0)` (or `isapprox` explicitely with accordingly chosen tolerances). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13001800/1346276

Comment: Looking at the determinant can be misleading; consider the determinant of a 100 by 100 matrix which is 0.1 on the diagonal and zero otherwise. The long-standing, conventional way to gauge how "invertible" a matrix is, is to look at the so-called condition number, which is defined as the ratio of largest to smallest eigenvalues; this is a measure of the error-inflating action of the matrix. There are ways to approximate the condition number without actually calculating the eigenvalues. A web search for that term will find some resources.

Comment: As others have said, the determinant can be misleading. That said, when I calculate `det(A)` in Julia 1.8, it returns _exactly_ 0.0.

Comment: Another thing: there's no reason to write `A::Matrix{Int64} = Matrix{Int64}([...])`, that is completely redundant, you can just write: `A = [1 2 -3; -3 1 -2; 5 3 -4]`.

Comment: Thank you everyone your comments. @DNF that's strange as I got about 6.21e-15. Also I write codes primarily in java, and c++, that's why I have a benign habit of specifying the type (`Matrix{Int64}` in this case).  @RobertDodier Thank you, I'll google about eigenvalues, and conditions number.  @Stef No, I couldn't find `det_bareiss` function, gues I'll have to install some packages.

Comment: Maybe search for the keyword *reciprocal condition*, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are working with integer matrices, this should work fairly well:

```
isinvertible(A) = !isapprox(det(A), 0)
```

For floating point I would perhaps change the matrix to BigFloat type and decide on the parameters of isapprox() that then work for your application. For example

```
isinvertible(A::Matrix{Float64}) = !isapprox(det(BigFloat.(A)), 0, atol = 1e-18)
```